# How to edit/properly fix a DVD VOB/BUP/IFO file?

Tags: ffmpeg, vlc-media-player, video-editing, vob

### Intro

I have a **[DVDISO](https://file.org/extension/dvdiso)** file, and opening it doesn't work because my built-in disk mounter can't read it.

So, I open it up with **[VLC](https://www.videolan.org/)** and all looks fine. When booting it up it's supposed to take you to a screen where you can select what clip you want to see. Remember this as the selection screen, and it has 3 clips and a PLAY ALL button. The first clip works... *Partially*. If you skip too far, VLC kicks you back to the selection screen. The 2nd and 3rd clips do not work and kick you back on sight.

### Cracking it Open

So, I get some software to open & extract the ISO's files and the first thing it tells me is that a few `BUP` and `IFO` files are corrupted, and a `VOB` file as well. Everything comes out and I don't really know how to work with `BUP` or `IFO`.

### Editing

The `VOB` file seems a little corrupted so I ran it through `ffmpeg` as: `ffmpeg -i './VTS_01_1.VOB' -c copy './PARTLYBADBUTFIXED.VOB'` So it does not break while in VLC.

#### Commands:

To clip the never corrupted vob: `ffmpeg -t 00:13:13 -i 'NEVERCORRUPTED.VOB' 'WHATIWANTPART1.VOB'`

To clip part of the corrupted vob: `ffmpeg -ss 00:13:13 -i 'PARTLYBADBUTFIXED.VOB' 'WHATIWANTPART2.VOB'`

Long story short: I then tried to create a new `VOB` by getting a uncorrupted clip, and clipping a unique part of the 'fixed' file which luckily wasn't broken, and concated it as such:

`ffmpeg -i 'concat:uncorrupted.vob|fixed.vob' -codec copy fixed.vob`

### Question

I'm not really sure if this file would work if I decided to plug it back in, which I haven't started yet but the filesize is extremely questionable. The og VOB was 1.07~ GB, and my fixed/edited VOB is 667 MB. Any suggestions? `ffmpeg` **probably wasn't the correct software to use, due to some of the buffer underflow errors & 'incorrect' timestamps.**

The VOB itself is supposed to be `16:41` in length, but VLC reads it as 3:41. Playing it, it clearly shows me that it has all clips but the timing is really screwed up. **This is my first time ever working with .VOB, .BUP, and .IFO files.**

Here is `ffprobe`'s thoughts:

Edited VOB by me:

```
  Duration: 00:16:41.53, start: 0.534667, bitrate: 5583 kb/s
    Stream #0:0[0x1bf]: Data: dvd_nav_packet
    Stream #0:1[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 720x576 [SAR 64:45 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:2[0x80]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 448 kb/s
```

OG, Still corrupted:

```
  Duration: 00:03:27.62, start: 0.280633, bitrate: 41372 kb/s
    Stream #0:0[0x1bf]: Data: dvd_nav_packet
    Stream #0:1[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 720x480 [SAR 32:27 DAR 16:9], 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Stream #0:2[0x80]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 448 kb/s
```

OG, But after I tried my best with ffmpeg to fix it:

```
  Duration: 00:16:42.66, start: 0.533367, bitrate: 8524 kb/s
    Stream #0:0[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 720x480 [SAR 32:27 DAR 16:9], 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x80]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 448 kb/s
```

*So, is there something that will help me edit/look at BUP,IFO,VOB files better?*